# How to insert sub string of a mysql column into empty columns within loop using php?

Tags: php, mysql, substring

I have a phpMyadmin database table with last three varchar rows: Location, lat, long

'Location' has latitude and longitude numbers that I separated using sub string and assigned to variables. I am trying to insert these variable into last two row in the table named: 'lat' and 'long.

This is what I have (does not show any error):

Problem: Does not insert anything in 'lat' and 'long'

```
if($result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM eStore")){
if($count = $result->num_rows){ 


echo "All available data: ";
while($row = $result->fetch_object()){ 
echo $row->Location, '<br/>' , '<br/><br/>';
        $long = substr($row->Location, -36, -20); // works
        $lat = substr($row->Location, -18, -1); //works
        $db->query("INSERT INTO eStore (lat, long) VALUES ('$lat', '$long')"); // does not work
    }
    $result->free();
}
}
```

DB structure:
[image]

**Fixed:** Changed name long to something else. I did not realize long was a reserved keyword. Thanks @RightClick

Comment: you're using `INSERT`, which will create a new row in your database.  It sounds like what you want to do is update the last 2 columns of an existing row.  Check out `UPDATE`, you'll need to have some column act as an id so that you update the correct row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query to update that row, not insert a new one with only 2 values.

```
$db->query("UPDATE eStore SET lat='$lat', long='$long' WHERE Location='".$row->Location."' ");
```

This query could update the lat & long values for multiple rows if they happen to have identical locations.  I don't think that would be a problem, since the lat and long values are derived from that.  If it is a problem, you need another column to act as an id

Comment: Using update instead - did not work for me; does not show any error

Comment: put this `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your file so you can see errors.  I just realized that you said Location is a varchar, so I wrapped single quotes around it, it might work now.  Try echoing out the query so you can inspect it or try manually running those query echoes in phpMyAdmin.  If none of that helps, you might want to share the db table structure so we know what columns you have.

Comment: edited code gives the following error:

( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"' "' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)

Comment: did you copy the whole line or just put the single quotes in?  if you assign the `$row->Location` to a variable you can put it in the query just as with $lat and $long, I think the object property makes the query kind of clunky.

Comment: awesome, glad I could help.  Will you mark it "answered"?  Also, you can use reserved words if you put backticks around them. Those are the thing on the tilda key.... but I don't know how to show it because backticks are reserved in stack overflow.  But anyway, congrats on solving it